# Why use %hiadj in movia?

Tags: assembly, nios

1. Can we use

`orhi r8,r0,%hi(0xffffffff)`

`addi r8,r0,%lo(0xffffffff)`

instead of the`%hiadj` at `orhi`?

2. Or must it be

`orhi r8,r0,%hi(0xffffffff)`

`ori r8,r0,%lo(0xffffffff)`

If I insist on using `%hi` at `orhi`?

3. Is the result of `%hiadj(0xffffffff)`= `0x0001`?
4. Then wouldn't

`orhi r8,r0,%hi(0xffffffff)`

`addi r8,r0,%lo(0xffffffff)`

produce `0x0001ffff` at `r8`? The 32-bit address isn't preserved.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can but it won't do what you think it does.
2. The `ori r8,r0,%lo(0xffffffff)` overwrites the result of the previous instruction so that makes no sense.
3. No, it is `0x0000` (`0xffff + 1`)
4. "Then" it would, but since it isn't, it doesn't :)

The `addi` uses sign extension and the `%hiadj` compensates for that by adding bit #15. After `orhi r8,r0,%hiadj(0xffffffff)` `r8` is `0x00000000`. The `addi r8,r0,%lo(0xffffffff)` assembles to `addi r8,r0,0xffff` but that immediate is sign extended by the cpu at runtime to `0xffffffff`. This, when added to `0x00000000` obviously gives `0xffffffff`. A better example would be trying to load `0x0001ffff`. Here, `%hiadj` will give `0x00020000` so adding the sign extended `0xffffffff` will again produce the correct result.